# How to loop through given arguments to print argument name and value with a Bash function?

Tags: bash

I want to write a helper function for my Bash scripts that print out the variables being set and their default values, before executing the rest of the script.

I can do what I want without a function:

```
host="postgres.database.com"
port="5432"
username="dbadmin"
dbname="test"

# Code below needs to be a function
for argument in host port username dbname
do
    echo "$argument: ${!argument}"
done
```

The output is:

```
host: postgres.database.com
port: 5432
username: dbadmin
dbname: test
```

However, I'd like to reuse this code in other scripts like so:

```
print_arguments $host $port $username $dbname
```

I've searched various ways of printing the variable name but not its value, however none of them seemed to work for me. As you can see below, I've tried to use shell parameter expansion and variable indirection:

```
print_arguments() {
    for argument in "$@"
    do
        echo "${!argument*}" "$argument"
        echo "${argument@A}" "$argument"
    done
}
```

The results usually look like:

```
argument postgres.database.com
argument 5432
argument dbadmin
argument test
```

Where `argument` is the variable name used in the `for` loop. I want to make it be able to resolve to the original variable name, e.g. `host` or `port`.

Comment: With the calling convention you're using, that information is simply lost. A command's argv is a list of strings; how those strings were formed or where they came from isn't retained.

Comment: (Consider in particular when you aren't using quotes: `print_arguments $host $port $username $dbname` has no guarantee whatsoever that the contents of `host` will become `$1`; if `host='*'`, f/e, the number of arguments would depend on the number of files in your current directory, so any kind of tracking would need to follow through the string-splitting and glob-expansion phases of execution. If you want a 1:1 relationship to even *exist* in a guaranteed way, you need to quote the expansions: `print_arguments "$host" "$port" "$username" "$dbname"`).

Comment: (...backing up to double down on my point, though: Consider also the case `host='' port='somehost 1234'` -- would you want `$1` to be recognizable as having come from `$port`? That's a lot of magic/tracking the shell would need to do).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the variable *names* rather than their *values* to `print_arguments`.

```
print_arguments host port username dbname
```

Then the loop you have up top works.

```
print_arguments() {
    for argument in "$@"
    do
        echo "$argument: ${!argument}"
    done
}
```